# What is proper way to define define-key in emacs

Tags: macos, emacs, key-bindings, spacemacs, evil-mode

I am trying to make toggle insert/normal mode in evil in spacemacs.
I have successfully accomplished that with code down there. But LED light next to Caps-lock on my macbook pro 2018 13' stoped working. So i am trying to switch led on my caps-lock with script.

I am using karabiner-elements to remap caps-lock to f13. When emacs records f13 it changes state to evil-normal-state or evil-insert-state.

The problem starts, when i want to add another command to run when f13 aka caps-lock ist pressed. Its `(shell-command "/Users/atrumoram/setleds +caps")`. Which turns the light on caps-lock or turns it off. I was trying to make my own function `defun`. But i really cannot make it work together. In the end i would like to have something like this.

**This is code that toggles insert/normal mode in evil using capslock**

```lisp
  (define-key evil-insert-state-map (kbd "<f13>") 'evil-normal-state)
  (define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "<f13>") 'evil-insert-state)
```

**In the end i would like to have something like this.**

```lisp
  (define-key evil-insert-state-map (kbd "<f13>") 'evil-normal-state (shell-command "/Users/atrumoram/setleds +caps"))
  (define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "<f13>") 'evil-insert-state (shell-command "/Users/atrumoram/setleds -caps"))
```

*Is there some way somebody can help me out? Looking forward for your ideas.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A key can only be bound to one function at a time, so in order for two things to happen when you press the key, you need to create a function, make it "interactive", and bind that to the key you want.

This function performs the two actions, one after the other:

```
(defun my-evil-normal-state-and-set-caps-led ()
  (interactive)
  (evil-normal-state)
  (shell-command "/Users/atrumoram/setleds +caps"))
```

Since it's declared as an `interactive` function, you can test it with `M-x my-evil-normal-state-and-set-caps-led`.

Then it's just a matter of:

```
(define-key evil-insert-state-map (kbd "<f13>") 'my-evil-normal-state-and-set-caps-led)
```

And vice versa for switching to insert state.

Comment: At first i'd like to thank you for your help.
But there is some kind of error, ```Symbol's function definition is void: evil-insert-mode```. Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: Not sure, but I think it should be `evil-insert-state` instead of `evil-insert-mode`.